# How make select as with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have this Track Schema  `{"_id": '123', "external_id": 'abc', "name": 'make work'}` and I have queryng `external_id` as songId and `name` as songTitle. How make this?

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const trackEsquema = new Schema({
    external_id: { type: String, unique: true },
    name: String,
});

const Track = mongoose.model('Track', trackEsquema);

const songs = await Track.find({}, { "_id": 0, "songId": "$external_id", "songTitle": "$name"});
```